# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'DP1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, error-code, mysql-error-1062

I have a table `distributor_warehouse` which has an auto-incremented coulmn `dpID`. I cannot insert row after inserting first row. I had seen similar queries like this but everywhere got answers that the column needs to be auto-incremented which is already done in mine.

```
mysql> desc distributor_warehouse;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dpID       | varchar(12)   | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| cpID       | varchar(12)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| QTY        | int(6)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COST_PRICE | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SELL_PRICE | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from distributor_warehouse;
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| dpID | cpID | QTY  | COST_PRICE | SELL_PRICE |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| DP1  | CP5  |   10 |    3000.00 |    3100.00 |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO distributor_warehouse(cpID,QTY,COST_PRICE,SELL_PRICE) VALUES ('CP6',150,999,1500);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'DP1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

`dpID` is made auto-incremented by using a trigger.

This is my table. I had inserted Row 1 successfully then while inserting Row 2 the problem is occurring.

```
mysql> desc autoid;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
| tg_distributor_warehouse_id | INSERT | distributor_warehouse | BEGIN
INSERT INTO autoid VALUES(NULL);
SET NEW.dpID = CONCAT('DP',LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),1,''));
END |
```

Comment: then we need to see the trigger's code.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan given

Comment: What is the point of this trigger?

Comment: to concatenate the string 'DP' with the ```auto increment``` value

Comment: I suggest _not_ doing this.  If you want to display `DP` followed by some auto increment value, then just do this when you query.

Comment: can you provide an example ?

Comment: Please for code questions give a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy I have given an example of the problem am facing.

Comment: Please give all code in your question needed to cut & paste & run. PS The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is 1 when you insert with error. Why do you think it would be different? If you don't, why you think DP1 can be inserted again?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, code works fine for me.

Comment: @philipxy I don't want ```DP1``` to be inserted again. I want a new row with ```DP2``` ad id.

Comment: So answer my other question. (The data you give has a DP1 already. Are you explaining clearly? [mre])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be fine

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t(dpid varchar(12), cpid varchar(12), qty int,cost_price decimal(10,2),sell_price decimal(10,2));
create table t1(id int auto_increment primary key);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter$$
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row
begin
    insert into t1 values (null);
    SET NEW.dpID = CONCAT('DP',LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(),1,''));
end$$
delimiter;

INSERT INTO t(cpID,QTY,COST_PRICE,SELL_PRICE) VALUES ('CP6',150,999,1500);


INSERT INTO t(cpID,QTY,COST_PRICE,SELL_PRICE) VALUES ('CP6',150,999,1500);
select * from t;

+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| dpid | cpid | qty  | cost_price | sell_price |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| DP1  | CP6  |  150 |     999.00 |    1500.00 |
| DP2  | CP6  |  150 |     999.00 |    1500.00 |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yeah that's where I am having confusion, same like this table I have another table **(exactly same as this)** which is working fine completely

Comment: If we cannot reproduce the error then there's not much we can do. You need to do a bit more digging. - does this error happen on a multi insert, are there any triggers on autoid, does anything else run against autoid which might revert the id, are these inserts in a transaction, is there a rollback occurring on autoid somehow...

Comment: 1. This error is happening on multi-insertion,   2. yes there are 3 triggers on ```autoid``` (one I've given in the post and the other 2 associated with 2 more tables),   3. didn't understood your question,   4. yes these are inserts in a transaction,   5. didn't understood your question

Comment: The only way that you can get the error is if the autoid value is set back to 1 after the first insert  - your going to have to plough through your code base to see where that might happen